# Access 2013 Creating Relationships between Tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

Is it possible to create a 0:* relationship between tables in access? For instance, I have a "Branch" table and a "Staff" table. The Branch can have 1 to many staff, but a staff can manage zero to 1 branch.

Is there a way to represent the constraints that a staff may only manage zero to 1 branch? Or is there only a way to show one-to-one relationships and one-to-many relationships in Access 2013?

Comment: In Access 2013 you could use an event-driven [Data Macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) to enforce the business rule. Have you explored that option? Also, you say that a Staff can only manage at most one Branch, but can a Branch have more than one Manager?

Comment: @GordThompson I have not. The project and class only provide a surface-level introduction into Access. I am implementing a database from a given ER diagram with no assumptions that specify whether or not a Branch can have more than one Manager. The only assumptions are given from the relationships I mentioned above. When I create a relationship between the tables in Access, it recognizes the student manages branch table as a 1 to many relationship; however, I would like that relationship to be recognized as 0..1, since a student may only manage 0..1 branch.